# Move add to cart in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I would like to have "add to cart" button nearby the price like in the picture.

By default, the button is placed after the price in the code, and I would like to move the button in the same tag of the price.

But I don't know which template of Woocommerce I have to edit to make this.

Thank's !

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can change the priority/order by removing and re-adding the parts you want the position changed - like this:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
```

**Drop this piece of code into your functions.php to take effect.**

Comment: Great answer, thanks! And with this [visual hook guide](https://hooks.wpdesk.org/product/belt/), I can freely move where I want to.